# How to add scopes to explicit HTTP requests to Google Calendar API?

Tags: python, django, api, google-api, python-requests

I am try to called the Calendar REST api using python's requests library in a django web application. I have made use of django-social-auth to login the user using Google accounts.

Following the related code for requests -

```
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        social = request.user.social_auth.get(provider='google-oauth2')
        response = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList',
            params={'access_token': social.extra_data['access_token']})
        print(response.text)

    return render(request, 'main/index.html')
```

I am getting the following error message in the response body - 
`Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.`

I am guess we have to add a scopes variable to the request but not quite sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to follow the offical Python sample [Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python)

Scopes is just an array so you should be able to add more then one.  Remember though if you change the scope in your code you need to reauthencate the user before its going to pick up the change so the user has to grant consent to the new scope.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import datetime
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
    Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Calendar API
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
    print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                        maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                        orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])

    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        print(start, event['summary'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```